# System.setProperty in JUnit tests

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have two tests, we'll call them test A and test B.

In test A we have this line

```
System.setProperty("<interface>", "<implementation>);
```

In test B we have that same line.

When both lines exist, test B fails. When I comment out the line in test A, test B succeeds. If I do a

```
System.clearProperty("<interface>")
```

test B fails.

I have a similar issue with tests C and D with a different interface property. Test C sets it, test D does not. When I comment out the set call, D passes. When I don't. D fails. When I call clear, D fails.

Calling clear and commenting out the line both cause B and D to have the "correct" value in that system property, however they fail when I call clear (despite having the same value as when the line is commented out) and succeed when commenting out. Anyone have any ideas why this is the case?

Snippet showing what it does

```
System.setProperty("INTERFACE_NAME", "IMPLEMENTATION_NAME");

//getOBJECT will now return a type of IMPLEMENTATION_NAME
INTERFACE mockedINTERFACE = INTERFACE.getDirectory().getOBJECT(domain);
```

Comment: What are you using the system property for? Can you share a code snippet?

Comment: It's setting an implementation to be used for an interface. The code snippet I sent is what I have in my test, just with the actual class names obfuscated (since it's would reveal my employer). Let me grab the next could lines.

Comment: Adding it to the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is a two-parter, and neither parts are good.

I was able to get the whole test suite running about 20% of the time by adding PowerMock in to tests A and C. Tests B and D were already using it. This makes me think that PowerMock is somehow the root cause of this. We can't rip it out of the project yet, but it's been on our todo list for about a year.

I undid the PowerMock changes because 20% isn't enough to actually say it's working. Instead I ended up changing maven surefire's forkmode to pertest, and having each test run in a separate JVM allows all tests to run and pass in maven.

I hate all of this but it technically works. Good luck, if anyone else stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 8):

Tests are supposed to be independent from one another. If they change global state e.g. system properties, they should revert the change after the test is executed.

Ensure that each of your tests passes when run separately and then add `@Before` and `@After` methods to revert the changes to the global state.

```
private String oldValue;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  oldValue = System.getProperty("key");
  System.setProperty("key", ...);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
  if (oldValue != null) {
    System.setProperty("key", oldValue);
  }
}
```

Do note that property being not set by default is tricky, maybe use `Optional<String>`.

Comment: So unfortunately the property is null before it is set, and doing a set with the old value causes a null pointer. Doing a System.clearProperty reverts it to null, but the next test still fails despite null being the "correct" value it expects.

Comment: That's the main confusion. Commenting out the line and doing a System.clearProperty both cause the property to be null, but only one of them causes the subsequent test to succeed. I don't understand how that's possible unless there's some other side effect to System.setProperty that I'm unaware of.

Comment: @Neal it's impossible to tell without seeing code and stack trace, maybe the property is not `null` but just empty String? `System.xxxProperty()` methods have no magic attached unless your project implemented something custom.

Comment: It is null. I've done prints/asserts around the set method call as well as at the start of the subsequent tests. No custom implementation of System stuff. I'm stumped.